# Yii сквозная авторизация по имени юзера?

Tags: php, yii

при помощи getenv("username")

могу узнать текущего юзера.

как на вкладке логин реализовать кнопку чттобы узнать есть ли такой пользователь в базе ?

что-то вроде

```
else if (getenv("username") == $user->id )
{
$this->_id = $user->id;
$this->username = $user->login;
$this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
}
```

проверить то в принципе могу.

login.php

```
<h1>Вход</h1>

<p></p>

<div class="form">
    <?php
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'login-form',
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
        'clientOptions' => array(
            'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        ),
    ));
    ?>

    <p class="note">Поля с <span class="required">*</span> обязательны.</p>

    <div class="row">       
        <?php echo CHtml::label('Имя', 'n'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'username'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">       
        <?php echo CHtml::label('Пароль', 'p'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model, 'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'password'); ?>
        <p class="hint">
            Для получения данных для входа обратитесь к администратору
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="row rememberMe">
        <?php echo $form->checkBox($model, 'rememberMe'); ?>        
        <?php echo CHtml::label('Запомнить', 'r'); ?>  
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'rememberMe'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Вход'); ?>

    </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
    <?php
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'ldap_login',
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
        'clientOptions' => array(
            'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        ),
    ));
    ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Вход под текущим пользователем'); ?>
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

нужно чтобы по второй кнопке в useridentity проходила проверка

```
$ldapuser = User::model()->find('LOWER(login)=?', array(strtolower(getenv("username"))));


else if ($ldapuser)
        {
            $this->_id = $ldapuser->id;        
            $this->username = $ldapuser->login;
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
```

Comment: Вызывай SQL или через ActiveRecord, ищи юзера по полю имени

Comment: "при помощи getenv("username") могу узнать текущего юзера." - это вряд ли.

Comment: да нет. реально могу. даж проверка проходит. только нужно две разные кнопки сделать